# align left and right div on all the screens with no compromise on image resolution.Entire image should be visible on any screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

website is in 100% structure.so Leftside has two divs one is image and other is text and right side has an image.Both the left side and right side div should be aligned on any screen.No compromise on image resolution and it should not be chopped out.

it is implemented here http://heydays.no/project/dinesen/

My link :http://multia.in/mthemes/portfolio_image.html

Please help..

Comment: time for you to learn about `media-queries` and `responsive-design`....if u still get stucked, come back with a better formal question....not spoon feeding request!! :)

Comment: I am sorry for the question formation.I really need help.I tried to use it as an background image.even if I use background-size cover or contain image still gets cut.I also tried using jquery to make left and right division height equal,alignment issue is resolved but image gets pixalated.Need some way through which I can resize the image depending on div's height and width without losing its quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can try like this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    <img src=""/>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Style**

```
.row {
  display:table;
}

.row .left, .row .right{
  display:table-cell;
  width:50%;
}
```